# rewind(file pointer) and then fwrite. Won't fwrite overwrite the file contents? C

Tags: c, file, fwrite, overwrite, seek

I came acroos this somewhere.

A file is being written and then rewind(fileptr) is done and then what should be written to the beginning of the file is written. But writing at the beginning, won't it overwrite the contents of the file? Please advise.

Comment: Probably yes, but you should post your code so we can see what you're talking about.

Answer (score 4):

#### Technically, ***yes***

Yes, the file will be overwritten, but only for the length of the write. If the file is longer, in most cases (ordinary files on mainstream systems) the remaining bytes will be unchanged.

However, you may actually be wondering if the file will be *truncated* at that point: usually (same cases) ***no***. Technically, truncation is *implementation-defined* for text files, and ***no*** for binary files.

I would be surprised if a modern system even *had* a text-vs-binary distinction, certainly Unix, Linux, and BSD systems don't, and I suspect that the *implementation-defined* weasel-words were put in for some now-decommissioned fossil. If so, then in *all* important cases the remaining bytes will be unchanged and the file will not be truncated.

Now, the file API is used for many things that don't implement the complete list of file abstractions: think UDP sockets, terminals, tape drives, random controllers for non-storage hardware, etc. It would be unwise, to say the least, to even *use* a buffered I/O package to write such channels, but perhaps they are the reason for the gap in the specification.

Comment: *Unless* the file was opened in append mode, in which case `rewind` moves the file position, and then `fwrite` writes to the end of the file anyway. From the question it looks as though that isn't the case here ("what should be written to the beginning of the file is written"), I just mention it for completeness.

Comment: Heh, good point, and together we have beaten just about every technicality to a ... *[-insert bloody metaphor-]*

Comment: Note that POSIX requires binary and text mode to be identical.